# Ansible insatllation through brew and pip in mac

Tags: ansible

What is the difference between brew installation and pip installation in mac

- Is there any supporting packages ?

Please give me some good ways to install ansible

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install ansible
```

I prefer a installation via brew. I see the following pro's:

- integration better geared towards mac (pip is more general purpose)
- I try to install everything via brew (not pip for python, npm for javasscript...)
- upgrade mechanism seems better to me (as far as I know upgrading every pip package is a bit hacky)

Comment: can you please give me one sample exmple ansible script to develop in local machine?

Answer (score 0):

The ansible documentation recommends installation via pip :

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements

[image]
I trust the product documentation more than the hearsay. Arguments like "I try to install everything via brew" do not apply here.

I recommend using pip as well, with a good python versions management and virtual environment.

I am using myself a combination of pyenv + venv (the latter is a module in recent versions of python in the standard library) and run Ansible on a control node in Mac OS in a python virtual env. It gives full control and definitely is not "hacky". The brew way is relying on system python on the other hand puts ansible in a Cellar site packages, ties it to a particular version of python with all its consequences and surprises.

To the OP - please read the ansible [user guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/index.html) and getting started documentation first before asking "please give me one sample".